# Is there any time.h function to get the date 14 days?

Tags: c, function, time, project, time.h

In my case I need to get the current date and the date 14 days later as a time limit for returning a book. Is there any such function or a manipulation to an existing function?

Comment: The value returned by `time()` is in seconds, so add `14*24*60*60`?  You can break either one up into date and time with `localtime_r()`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Not all two-week spans are 14•24•60•60 seconds. Calendars are hard.

Comment: It actually works. Can t believe I didn t think of it. Thank you!

Comment: @Names: If you are doing this for a class assignment, that may be a tolerable solution. If you ever need to work with calendars in professional development, be aware they are fairly complicated. As an example, if you calculate the date that is 14•24•60•60 seconds from the start of today and there is a [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) added in the next two weeks, then the time that is 14•24•60•60 days from the start of today will be in the 13th day from today, not the 14th. This is just one of a number of complications in calendar systems.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think DST transitions are a better example of the problem you're talking about.  Unless something has changed since the last time I looked, all Unix and Linux systems deny the existence of leap seconds, and are required to do so by Posix, so leap seconds can't actually cause this sort of problem.  (If `time_t` were implemented in a way that honored leap seconds, and if that alternate definition *did* cause the problem you speak of, I believe `time_t` would be unusable.  I believe that a proper Unix leapsecond implementation would have to be outside of `time_t`.)

Answer (score 1):

Given a broken-down time structure, `struct tm`, the Standard C (and POSIX) function [`mktime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html) will return a `time_t` value associated with the value.  Further, the elements of the structure passed in can be out of their normal ranges, and `mktime()` will normalize them.  So, you could add 14 to the `tm_mday` element of the structure, and `mktime()` will both give you the `time_t` value for the corresponding time and also normalize the elements of the structure, thus giving you the correct day of the month, month of the year, and year number.